# How much does the SpaceX Starship flex during the Flop maneuver?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship

Poring over the woes (and sucesses) of Starship prototypes SN 5-11, I had read they were trying a thinner stainless steel skin in later iterations.

The flop maneuver places the centers of drag at the ends (fins), while the center of mass is near the middle.  This is not unlike the strategy of breaking a stick over your knee.

SN5 and SN6 performed flawlessly, but their bodies were subjected only to shorter term vertical loading, without the flop descent configuration.

Judging by the (notorious) gas leaks and explosions of 8-11,  could excessive flexing (and potential plumbing damage) be avoided with a stronger, perhaps more squat design?

Successful re-entry vehicles, such as capsules and shuttles, seem a bit more symmetrical, which adds strength.

Comment: @Organic Marble thanks.  The rocket body actually looks pretty solid in descent, not sure about the innards.  Much to be done, but they will be successful.

Comment: The mass is actually concentrated in the ends - header tanks in the top and engines in the bottom. The center is a mostly empty tube.

Comment: @SF There seem to be something going seriously wrong with their plumbing.  We'll look to see if SN15 corrects it.  This design must re-enter with loaded highly flammable fuel tanks.  Certainly hope they get it right.

Comment: It's considerably more complex - matters of sloshing fuel after the turn, and supplying uninterrupted stream of fuel to the engine immediately after. Cavitation, bubbles, shortages of supply do more than reduce thrust - these turbopumps aren't meant to churn vacuum while spinning at full power; without constant load of liquid to pump they are prone to spin up so hard they damage themselves and infrastructure around.

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes for a fairly innocuous question.

Comment: SN8 had too low pressure in the methane header tank, I don't think it was ever publicly disclosed what the problem with SN9 was, SN10 had a problem with helium ingestion into the turbo pump, and the investigation into SN11 has only just started and nothing has been publicly revealed. So, at least according to publicly available information, there was never any mention of gas leaks, and the explosions of SN8–10 were clearly the *consequence* of the landing failure, not the *cause* (most obviously SN10). For SN11, the explosion may or may not have been the cause, we don't know yet.

Comment: What are those "notorious gas leaks"? I have never heard about them.

Comment: Jorg, wasn't SN 10 on fire before it landed?  But this is very advanced (but expensive) research.  I would ask for SN 12 with thicker steel, pressurized main tanks, and a parachute.  I would fly it like SN 6 up and down many times, then go for 10 K *no flop, just parachute*, relight, land.  Sometimes, smaller steps are better.